# Selenium webdriver loops through all pages, but only scraping data for first page

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape data through multiple pages (36) from a website to gather the document number and the revision number for each available document and save it to two different lists. If I run the code block below for each individual page, it works perfectly. However, when I added the while loop to loop through all 36 pages, it will loop, but only the data from the first page is saved.

```
#sam.gov website
url = 'https://sam.gov/search/?index=sca&page=1&sort=-modifiedDate&pageSize=25&sfm%5Bstatus%5D%5Bis_active%5D=true&sfm%5BwdPreviouslyPerformedWrapper%5D%5BpreviouslyPeformed%5D=prevPerfNo%2F'

#webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options_, executable_path = r'C:/Users/439528/Python Scripts/Spyder/chromedriver.exe' )
driver.get(url)

#get rid of pop up window
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sds-dialog-0 > button > usa-icon > i-bs > svg'))).click()

#list of revision numbers
revision_num = []

#empty list for all the WD links
WD_num = []
substring = '2015'

current_page = 0

while True:
    
    current_page += 1
    if current_page == 36:
        #find all elements on page named "field name". For each one, get the text. if the text is 'Revision Date'
        #then, get the 'sibling' element, which is the actual revision number. append the date text to the revision_num list. 
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sds-field__name')
        wd_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('usa-link')
        for i in elements:
            element = i.text
            if element == 'Revision Number':
                revision_numbers = i.find_elements_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div")
                
                for x in revision_numbers:
                    a = x.text
                    revision_num.append(a)
                    
            
        #finding all links that have the partial text 2015 and putting the wd text into the WD_num list
        for link in wd_links:
            wd = link.text
            if substring in wd:
                WD_num.append(wd)
            
        
        print('Last Page Complete!')
        break
             
    else:
        #find all elements on page named "field name". For each one, get the text. if the text is 'Revision Date'
        #then, get the 'sibling' element, which is the actual revision number. append the date text to the revision_num list. 
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sds-field__name')
        wd_links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('usa-link')
        for i in elements:
            element = i.text
            if element == 'Revision Number':
                revision_numbers = i.find_elements_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div")
                
                for x in revision_numbers:
                    a = x.text
                    revision_num.append(a)
                    
            

        #finding all links that have the partial text 2015 and putting the wd text into the WD_num list
        for link in wd_links:
            wd = link.text
            if substring in wd:
                WD_num.append(wd)
            
        #click on next page
        click_icon = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located([By.ID,'bottomPagination-nextPage']))
        click_icon.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'main-container')))
```

Things I've tried:

- I added the WebDriverWait in order to slow the script down for the page to load and/or elements to be clickable/located
- I declared the empty lists outside the loop so it does not overwrite over each iteration
- I have edited the while loop multiple times to either count up to 36 (while current_page <37) or moved the counter to the top or bottom of the loop)

Any ideas? TIA.

**EDIT:** added screenshot of 'field name'
[image]

Comment: `find all elements on page named "field name".` where is field name ? I am getting 129 web element in the first page. Not sure which one would be field name? Can you upload a snapshot and let us know what is field name?

Comment: @cruisepandey, I added the screenshot. I identify the data I need by class name 'sds-field__name' but as you can see, there are multiple elements with that class name. So then I filtered by if the element == 'Revision Number'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactor your code and made things very simple.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options_, executable_path = r'C:/Users/439528/Python Scripts/Spyder/chromedriver.exe' )
    
    revision_num = []
    WD_num = []
    
    for page in range(1,37):
        url = 'https://sam.gov/search/?index=sca&page={}&sort=-modifiedDate&pageSize=25&sfm%5Bstatus%5D%5Bis_active%5D=true&sfm%5BwdPreviouslyPerformedWrapper%5D%5BpreviouslyPeformed%5D=prevPerfNo%2F'.format(page)
        driver.get(url)
        if page==1:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sds-dialog-0 > button > usa-icon > i-bs > svg'))).click()
    
        
        elements =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class,'usa-link') and contains(.,'2015')]")))
        wd_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='sds-field__name' and text()='Revision Number']/following-sibling::div")))
        for element in elements:
            revision_num.append(element.text)
    
        for wd_link in wd_links:
            WD_num.append(wd_link.text)
    
    print(revision_num)
    print(WD_num)
```

1. if you know only 36 pages to iterate you can pass the value in the url.
2. wait for element visible using webdriverwait
3. construct your xpath in such a way so can identify element uniquely without if, but.

**console output on my terminal**:

[image]

[image]